# How do I change the styling of a created list item when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that takes input and adds the text to a list with a checkbox. I am trying to make a function that crosses off items on a list when the corresponding checkbox is checked. I've been playing around with it for a while and I've noticed that the function only works if I code in the list items into the HTML before hand. The function will not work with list items that have been inputted by the user.

Function to add list items with checkbox:

```
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {

    let node = document.createElement("li");
    let text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(text); 

    node.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);

    let checkBox = document.createElement("input");

    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    checkBox.className = "checkbox";
    node.appendChild(checkBox);
}
```

Function to cross off list items when checkbox is checked:

```
let checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");

for (i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    checkBoxes[i].addEventListener("change", checkIt);
}

function checkIt(e) {
if(e.target.checked == false) {
    e.target.parentElement.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
else {
    e.target.parentElement.style.textDecoration = "none"; 
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm very new to JavaScript!

Comment: can you include your html? or at least a sample of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are running the for-loop that adds the eventListeners just once and after new list items are added, they're not being listened to. The simple solution is to add the eventListener when you create the new checkbox like this:

```
    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    checkBox.className = "checkbox";
    checkBox.addEventListener("change", checkIt);  // <-- add this
    node.appendChild(checkBox);
```

That way all new checkboxes will have something to do when changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class to your the element that you want to strike-through on click.

the structure needs to have the `checkbox` and the `text` you want to strike through on the same level:

```
div
  checkbox
  text
```

then you can use a css ::after pseudo selector to add animation to the text.

```
.checkbox:checked ~ .text {
  // animation of strikethrough css
}
```

the `~` selector is a "sibling" selector that will find a checkbox that is checked and run the css on the .text that is placed directly after the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow and javascript world, @TheWolf1494

As I understand, you are trying to bind your event handler function to checkboxes before you create them on DOM, when the document is ready. That means you are binding your function to nowhere.

Please try the following one;

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function () {

    // Your existing codes
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    checkBox.type = "checkbox";
    checkBox.className = "checkbox";

    // For test purpose
    checkBox.id = new Date().toISOString();
    // Bind the event handler here
    checkBox.onclick = function () {
        console.log(this.id + ' is ' + (this.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'))
    }

    node.appendChild(checkBox);
}
```